# How can you have Python packages in a C module?

Tags: python, c, module, pypi

I am learning how to produce Python moduels using C and the `Python.h` header, however I have only been able to produce a package that has a single module. Furthermore, I have also only been able to use C (no pure Python) in these modules as I cannot figure out how to add a Python file to the package and have it be inclued in the final uploaded version that goes to PyPi. I have also had trouble trying to have "sub-modules" such as `myModule.test`, where `test` can be used like this:

```py
from myModule.test import testFunction
```

My question is what sort of directory structure and files do I need in order to have some of the module written in C and some of it written in Python, potentially providing wrappers for the C functions. I would also like to be able to use "sub-modules" though this is less of an issue currently.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest looking at one of the many other packages that does this, e.g. [editdistance](https://github.com/roy-ht/editdistance)

Comment: In your example, does it matter that that project uses Cython?